# Changing the area which counts as being fit to bounding box

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Let's say I've got a full-screen google map, with a div which is on the left (but isn't, strictly speaking, an overlay or UI element of the map) and absolutely positioned.

Now let's say I have a bounding box (as in: [ [lat, lng], [lat, lng] ]which I want to have the map fit. What if I want it to take into consideration that div. I have the absolute position and the size of it in pixels. Is there something I can specify on the map to say "This area is off bounds, don't let the bounding box clash with it"?

Comment: Are you wanting to determine a LatLngBounds and if the 'left div' intersects the bounds, subtract the 'left div' coordinates from the bounding box and zoom?

Comment: Pretty much, yes :) I think you've got it!

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to place a bounding box around the map or are you trying to ensure that all markers are displayed within the map?
The api allows you to set up a bounding area so that when the map loads all points are visible within the map. The map will zoom or scale accordingly.

to setup bounds within your function add the following

```
    (function(){
    ..existing code 

    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var infowindow;   
    //Here I have an event listener that I have setup for the clicking of the markers 

    (function (i, marker) {
         google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {

            if (!infowindow) {
               infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            }

            infowindow.setContent('Location: ' + i);

            infowindow.open(map, marker);
            });
         })(i, marker);
          bounds.extend(places[i]);
       }
      map.fitBounds(bounds)

   })();
```

There are a few things happening here. Map is the name of my DIV layer the anonymous function would just be used to wrap everything. The reason I added the click event code was to also show how I can get the map to auto position whenever I click on a marker to view the info window (using the bounds.extend(places[i]). Places is the array of coordinates that I have collected. I didn't add all the code such as for the marker generation but I would normally place this block of code following that.  The bounds function as part of the api forces the map to auto position and zoom according to where the markers are located on the page. This ensures that when the map is rendered all markers are visible to the user. 
Not sure if this is what you wanted but if you can clarify I may be able to elaborate more.

Best of luck

Comment: Thanks :) but I don't think you're quite there. Basically, I'd like the map to respect the fact that there's a div hovering over it and take that into consideration when I ask it to and pan to a bounding box - i.e. so that the area of the bounding box is not underneath the div.